# Using sed with multiple conditions

Tags: bash, shell, sed, sh

I have a `.spec` file that has lines such as the following:

```
Requires: rpm_name           = 1.0.0
Requires: longer_rpm_name    = 1.0.1
```

I am putting together a script that will write to the `.spec` file and update the rpm versions with their respective new versions.

Using `sed` I can do something like `sed -i 's/Requires: rpm_name.*/Requires: rpm_name = 2.0.0'`. This will result in the following:

```
Requires: rpm_name = 2.0.0
Requires: longer_rpm_name    = 1.0.1
```

Rather than replace the entire line I would like to simply replace the version number that follows the `=` character such that the formatting of the line remains the same. I would like:

```
Requires: rpm_name          = 2.0.0
Requires: longer_rpm_name   = 1.0.1
```

I would like `sed` to find the line starting with `Requires: rpm_name` and then only replace the version number instead of the entire line. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an address specification at the beginning of the command to match the line. Then use a regexp in the `s` command to replace just the number at the end.

```
sed -i '/^Requires: rpm_name/s/[0-9.]*$/2.0.0/'
```

Answer (score 1):

Remember the part until the equal sign

```
sed -ri 's/(Requires: rpm_name.*)=/\1= 2.0.0/'
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed 's/\(\<rpm_name \+=\).*/\1 2.0.0/' input_file
Requires: rpm_name           = 2.0.0
Requires: longer_rpm_name    = 1.0.1
```